# Can iOS Support Deep-Links Within the HTTP Scheme?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Under Android, you can capture part of the "http" space and use it to deep-link into an app.  The YouTube app for example uses this so any links to http://www.youtube.com/ have the option of opening in the native app instead.

*Is it possible to do the same with iOS deep linking?*  My [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios%20deep%20linking%20scheme) shows examples only with custom schemes so I'm guessing not.

*If not, how could it be accomplished?*  Can I have my web server do a 302 redirect from the http url to a url with my custom scheme?

Or even better, how could I detect if the app is installed and either deep-link into it or send the user to the appropriate download page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can happily report that a redirect from a server's http address to a custom scheme works under both Android and iOS.  Would be better not to have to do this, though, so still looking for other ideas.

Here's the code I used in an otherwise empty App-Engine servlet:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String query = req.getQueryString();
    String deeplink =
            "example:/" +  // pathinfo includes leading slash
            req.getPathInfo() + (query != null ? "?" + query : "");
    resp.sendRedirect(deeplink);
}
```